# /usr/bin/env: python3.3: No such file or directory inside chroot

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

```
chroot --userspec 1000:1000 /var/lib/broot/sugar-build-3xlQJ /usr/bin/env -i 
PATH=/bin:  /usr/bin:/usr/sbin BROOT=yes XAUTHORITY=/home/broot/.Xauthority 
DISPLAY=:0 HOME=/home/broot LANG=C TERM=xterm-256color  
/bin/bash -lc "/home/broot/sugar-build/osbuild build"
```

can anyone explain the above command because the error seems to be in this only . I know what chroot basically does, so the problem seems to be that the python3.3 module is not in the chroot jail. so if that is the problem , how can i get python3.3 module inside the chroot jail.
Btw i am porting some modules from python2.7 to python3.3 and the above command is from those modules and it did work in python2.7.

Comment: Are the files in python3.3's path? A good place to put them/check is in the site-packages folder.

Comment: @MrAlias Which files?

Comment: Originally I was wondering about the modules you are try to port, but by your response I'm now wondering if you even have python3.3 installed under the new chroot?

Comment: i think that is the problem. I don't have python3.3 installed in the new chroot. How can i do that?

Comment: I'll assume you're using a Mac, so first let me say "good luck".  Likely you need to chroot to the root directory (without trying to run the script) and then [install](https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.3.3/) python3.3

Comment: Also if you can install [homebrew](http://brew.sh/), it usually solves a lot of headache down the road.

Comment: i'm using fedora 20 . and python3.3 is installed on my machine, so isn't there a way for chroot to use that version instead of python2.7 which it seems to use by default?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe updating you're question or asking a new one now that you have a clearer idea of what you are asking will interest others into helping :)

Comment: i already have that in my question :"so the problem seems to be that the python3.3 module is not in the chroot jail" , do you still think i should ask another question?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a chroot environment, everything you need must be copied from your installation.

Let's say your chroot environment starts under /var/chroot.

Let's say further that you want to be able to run "ls" (you don't have if you 
don't ever need to have the capability to run "ls", but let's say you do).
First you must copy /bin/ls to /var/chroot/bin/ls.
Now, "/bin/ls" requires a number of library files in order to run.
Let's say you discover one of them is called /lib64/libcap.so.
That means you have to copy /lib/libcap.so to /var/chroot/lib64/libcap.so
otherwise your /var/chroot/bin/ls will NOT run.
You do this for all the libraries that "ls" requires.

After all that is done, you can chroot to /var/chroot, and, voila, your "ls" now runs.

Same idea with any other commands, whether they are system commands such as "ls",
or compilers/interpreters such as python.

Comment: hey, i also think that this is how chroot works but what is confusing me is that the command that i mentioned in my post is the only chroot related command and they haven't explicitly installed python2.7 or anything but it was still able to run python2.7 files but now it is unable to run python3.3 files. am i missing something here?